# か in その日も彼は、森の人々が町にやってきて悪さをしないか、森の見回りをしていた

Tags: particles, embedded-question

> その日も彼は、森の人々が町にやってきて悪さをしないか、森の見回りをしていた

What does the "か" mean here? is it an "if" or is it something else? Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complement an appropriate verb after か, like ***to see/check/verify** if*.

So the sentence means *That day he was patrolling around the woods **to see** if the people there come to town and behave badly.*

---

Normally those *to see* etc. are omitted.

- 新情報がないか(どうか)ウェブで調べた Searched on the web (to see) if new info comes up
- 壊れてないか起動してみる (e.g. after spilling water over PC) Try booting the device (to check) if it isn't broken

Inserting (か)調べるために/確かめるために in the above sentences would sound lengthy.